# Simple variable assignment from two-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array with two key values, [program] and [balance], created by a MySQL SELECT statement in WordPress. I know what the values of [program] will be (they never change) - it's the balances I'm interested in.

For example:

```
*[program] = 'Sales', [balance] = 10,000*

*[program] = 'Commission', [balance] = 1,250*
```

All I want to do is assign the balance value to a variable, so I will have:

```
*$sales = (the balance for the Sales program)*

*$commission = (the balance for the Commission program)*
```

I know I'm being thick here, but I cannot see how to do this after about an hour of searching and screwing around with php. It's a total brain block and all the references I can find online talk about loops and echoing all the values and stuff.

Would appreciate a de-blocking!

Comment: Can you share the actual array (or a piece of it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//make a function
function findBalanceByProgram($inputArray,$program)
 //loop trough all the keys on the first dimension
 foreach($inputArray as $val){
    //check in the second dimension if your program is the same as the program you are checking for
    if($val['program']==$program) 
      //if so.. return the value and jump out of the function
      return $val['balance'];
  }
}

//an example of use.
echo findBalanceByProgram($yourArray,'sales');
```

Comment: Can you provide some commentary on your answer so that future visitors to SO will know what you're attempting?

Comment: Seperate the parameters $inputArray$program with a comma : $inputArray, $program

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid it would need a whole extra function, instead of being something simple. Thanks for the response - tested and working.